# Not getting the updated value of ng-model when ng-model is changed programmatically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

When I check master check-box all the children check-box should be checked and their content should also be shown when check-box is checked otherwise their content should not be shown but the issue is that child check-boxes are checked but their content is not shown when I check master check-box if I check child check-box manually its content is shown.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Angular Demo</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body data-ng-app="">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="parent"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-ng-show="parent" class="left">
                        It's master
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="child_1" data-ng-checked="parent"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-ng-show="child_1">
                        It's child 1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="child_2" data-ng-checked="parent"/>
                    </td>
                    <td data-ng-show="child_2">
                        It's child 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the issue.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="parent" data-ng-change="child_1= parent;
                            child_2=parent;" />
```

Please [click](http://jsfiddle.net/ali_92121/qg5gy5a2/) here to see the code.

Comment: setting model values like this from the view is not a good practice if you care about ease of maintenance and readability of your code

Answer (score 1):

You are not interacting with the child model - you are setting the checked property directly from the parent.

Instead, handle ng-checked for your parent:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="parent" ng-checked="parentChanged()"/>
```

And in your controller set the model of each child to parent value:

```
$scope.parentChanged = function(){
child_1 = parent;
child_2 = parent;
}
```

Also remove data-ng-checked="parent" from the children nodes your view.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="child_1">
...
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="child_2">
```

Comment: I want to show content when parent check-box is checked as well as when child check-box is checked manually

Comment: Something like this? http://plnkr.co/edit/iFAsXMS4dYQMYFhXcOcL?p=preview This example for illustration only, you should put this logic into your controller as described in my answer

Comment: I cannot do as you suggested because inputs are dynamic from server side using looping statment.

Comment: then I would move the looping to the client via ngRepeat, that would give you access to a data object on which to perform .forEach in your parentChanged() https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: I have checked your code and it works on version 1.4.0 there is syntax error using version 1.3.13.
I cannot assign multiple variables like below in version 1.3.13.
child_1=child_2=parent; 
I have done using below code and it worked.
child_1=parent;child_2=parent;

Comment: I was illustrating the mechanics of interaction in my plunkr above, not suggesting this as the final solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

You must set the property "child_1" like this :

```
<input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="child_1" data-ng-checked="child_1 = parent"/>
```

You can see how to do it : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/agskill/69p8ymdf/1/)

Comment: Your code only works when master check-box is checked but when I check child check-box it does not work.I want that it should work in 2 way using master check-box as well as child check-box.

Comment: Still there is an issue , I followed below steps.(1) I checked master check-box now all the check-boxes were checked and their contents were also shown. (2) I unchecked first child check-box but its contents was not hidden.